How to calculate or get the response time of an API?
using cypress i'm intercepting an API call and want to get how much the response time it took
cy.intercept("PATCH", "https://api.website.com/b2b2/**").as("myAPP")
cy.wait("@myAPP").then(({ request, response }) => {
    expect(response.duration).to.be.lessThan(2000)// => expected undefined to be a number or a date
    expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200)
}) 


In JavaScript, you can measure how fast an API call is by using performance API.
For example:


const start = performance.now();
fetch('https://api.example.com/data')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const end = performance.now();
      const responseTime = end - start;
      console.log(`Response time: ${responseTime} milliseconds`);
    });




there are many ways but You may try with

using JavaScript (Node.js and Fetch API):



const fetch = require('node-fetch');

(async () => {
    const startTime = Date.now();

    const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data');
    const data = await response.json();

    const endTime = Date.now();
    const responseTime = endTime - startTime;

    console.log(`Response Time: ${responseTime} ms`);
})();




Using Postman
Postman, a popular API testing tool, provides an easy way to measure response time.

Open Postman.
Send the API request.
After the request is completed, Postman displays the response time in the bottom-right corner under the "Response" section.
